# Combine two queries adding column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying combine two queries and add column *GroupParent* inside column *GroupKala*.

[image]
**Query 1:**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT K.Name, K.Info, K.Code, K.Barcode, P.Price, P.FinalPrice, M.Mojoodi, G.GroupKala
FROM dbo.Mojoodi_All(@P1,@P2,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT) M
INNER JOIN KalaList K ON M.ID_Kala=K.ID
INNER JOIN KalaPrice P ON K.ID=P.KalaID AND P.PriceID=1 AND P.[Type]=2
LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupKala G ON K.GroupID=G.ID
',N'@P1 varchar(10),@P2 varchar(10)','1399/01/01','1399/12/29'
```

[image]

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT G1.GroupKala AS [GroupName], G2.GroupKala AS [GroupParent]
FROM GroupKala G1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupKala G2 ON G1.ParentID=G2.ID
```

[image]

With Query 2 I can get GroupParent and I want join column group parent to Query 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT K.Name, K.Info, K.Code, K.Barcode, P.Price, P.FinalPrice, M.Mojoodi, G1.GroupKala AS [GroupName], G2.GroupKala AS [GroupParent]
FROM dbo.Mojoodi_All(@P1,@P2,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT) M
INNER JOIN KalaList K ON M.ID_Kala=K.ID
INNER JOIN KalaPrice P ON K.ID=P.KalaID AND P.PriceID=1 AND P.[Type]=2
LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupKala G1 ON K.GroupID=G1.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN GroupKala G2 ON G1.ParentID=G2.ID
',N'@P1 varchar(10),@P2 varchar(10)','1399/01/01','1399/12/29'
```